# Hover not working for the image gallery

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover

Image hover is not working in the below code. Whenever I try to hover on a particular image that particular image is not being displayed. But if I remove the second portion (In comments in code) from code then it's working perfectly.

```
     <div class="container marginbot-50">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                <div class="wow flipInY" data-wow-offset="0" data-wow-delay="0.4s">
                <div class="section-heading text-center">
                <h2 class="h-bold" style="margin-top:90px">1. Meadows Towers</h2>
                <div class="divider-header"></div>
                <p style="text-align:justify">It is a major construction firm.                         
                </p>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


     <div class="gallery" align="center"><br>
     <h4>Check details about project below</h4>

  <div class="thumbnails">
<img onmouseover="preview.src=img1.src" name="img1" src="img/works/1.jpg" alt="" />
<img onmouseover="preview.src=img2.src" name="img2" src="img/works/2.jpg" alt="" />
<img onmouseover="preview.src=img3.src" name="img3" src="img/works/3.jpg" alt="" />
<img onmouseover="preview.src=img4.src" name="img4" src="img/works/4.jpg" alt="" />
<img onmouseover="preview.src=img5.src" name="img5" src="img/works/5.jpg" alt="" />
 </div>

 <div class="preview" align="center">
 <img name="preview" src="img/works/1.jpg" alt=""/>
</div>

<!--*****************Second portion*******************-->

<div class="wow flipInY" data-wow-offset="0" data-wow-delay="0.4s">
<div class="section-heading text-center">
<h2 class="h-bold" style="margin-top:90px">2.Shangrilla</h2>
<div class="divider-header"></div>
<p style="text-align:justify"> Construction is a major construction firm.                        
Our goal is to reach all the section of people from 2BHK, 3BHK and 4BHK. 
</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>


     <div class="gallery" align="center"><br>
     <h4>Check details about project below</h4>

    <div class="thumbnails">
<img onmouseover="preview.src=img1.src" name="img1" src="img/works/1.jpg" alt="" />
<img onmouseover="preview.src=img2.src" name="img2" src="img/works/2.jpg" alt="" />
<img onmouseover="preview.src=img3.src" name="img3" src="img/works/3.jpg" alt="" />
<img onmouseover="preview.src=img4.src" name="img4" src="img/works/4.jpg" alt="" />
<img onmouseover="preview.src=img5.src" name="img5" src="img/works/5.jpg" alt="" />
 </div>

 <div class="preview" align="center">
  <img name="preview" src="img/works/1.jpg" alt=""/>
 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: _But if I remove the second portion (In comments in code)_.. where is it?

Comment: Why don't you add a common function for `onmouseover` and pass `this` as parameter?

Comment: Can you please elaborate or add a piece of code?

Comment: @HebleV If can provide a sample for your problem in a JSFiddle It will be much easier to help.

Comment: `jquery` solution or `javascript`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have this `function` which accepts `target` and `source` and changes to required **`target's src`**

```
function changeSrc(control,target)
{
     var targets=target.children[0]; //get its children
     targets.setAttribute('src',control.getAttribute('src'));//change its src
}
```

Your updated **HTML**

Instead of `onmouseover="preview.src=img1.src"` call function `onmouseover` as `onmouseover="javascript:changeSrc(this,this.parentElement.nextElementSibling)"`

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/9d59k3px/)**

The problem with your previous code was, there were 2 `elements` with same name `preview` and when you said `preview.src` it fetched list of `elements` and wasn't able to assign it to proper `preview - element`.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot. this is what exactly I was expectiong. So a piece of javascript was the that i was missing right?

Comment: piece of javascript is true, but if your current `DOM` structure changes then this code might not work.. Anyways.. Happy coding.. :)